# Android stops sending onTouch events

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have a custom view which I wish to handle touch events for. In particular, dragging a finger over the view should cause its contents to scroll. To do this, I have implemented the following onTouchListener:

```
private OnTouchListener graphOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onTouch called");
        System.out.println("view width: " + v.getWidth());
        System.out.println("view height: " + v.getHeight());
        System.out.println("view: " + v);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // First finger down
                System.out.println("ACTION_DOWN x: " + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
                startTouch(event.getX());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Last finger to be removed
                System.out.println("ACTION_UP x: " + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // A finger moves
                System.out.println("ACTION_MOVE x: " + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
                moveTouch(event.getX());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }  

        // The event has been handled, so return true
        return true;
    }
};
```

**This works as expected, unless the user moves their finger up or down while on the view. At this point, touch events stop being sent (as evidenced by a lack of output in LogCat).** However, using `adb shell getevent` still shows events being generated by touch movement.

Can anyone suggest how I can rectify this?

As requested, the layout XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="10dip">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
                <com.graphlib.ShaderAreaGraphView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200dip"
                    android:id="@+id/activity_power_realtime" android:background="#000000" />
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
                    <Button android:text="&lt;&lt;" android:id="@+id/goBackwardsButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:text="Zoom out" android:id="@+id/zoomOutButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:text="Zoom in" android:id="@+id/zoomInButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>
                    <Button android:text="&gt;&gt;" android:id="@+id/goForwardsButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please show us the layout xml.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, action_up is them removing their finger?  Wouldnt you want a `break;` after that to ensure action_move isn't fired after they remove their finger?

Comment: Yes, probably, but I'm not too fussed about that. I'll edit the code anyway to stop the distraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that the view is contained in a ScrollView. Removing the ScrollView fixes the problem.

Comment: Correct, my custom view was in a vertical scroll view and onTouch events worked horizontally in the custom view but stopped when moved finger vertically .

Answer (score 3):

you need write the break statement in each case. otherwise every case are executed.

```
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // First finger down
            System.out.println("ACTION_DOWN x: " + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
            startTouch(event.getX());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Last finger to be removed
            System.out.println("ACTION_UP x: " + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // A finger moves
            System.out.println("ACTION_MOVE x: " + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
            moveTouch(event.getX());
            break;
```

or you can put into the if ... else if condition

Comment: This has no effect, but I've edited the original code anyway.

Comment: what the problem you facing i test you listener it works perfectly give me the co-ordinate down, moving, and up time

Comment: Drag left and right a bit and then move upwards. After this moving left and right will not create events (at least not on the Nexus One or emulator I'm testing it on).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to solve this is to create a reference to the scroll view e.g. myScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollView). Then in onTouchEvent, ACTION_DOWN state:

> myScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

And in ACTION_UP

> myScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your switch, try adding

```
default:
    break;
```

Might not be the fix, but it's good practice to have that.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't fixed anything. I've updated the code with your suggestion.